# how to delete someone else's repo? (not forked)

Tags: github

There is someone else's repo in my github. I can't see the settings even if I try to delete it. How can I erase someone else's repo? This is not a forked repo.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "someone else's repo in my github"? Where do you see the repo? The screenshot you have attached doesn't show anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, you are added as a contributor to the repo and there is no way you can delete someone's repo without being the owner.